e{ } and e( ) Notation
I was reading An Introduction to the Theory of Numbers by Hardy and Wright, and on pages 66 and 67, I encountered the notation, as following


What does the $e( )$ and $e\{\}$ notation mean? Any help would be most appreciated! Thanks, BakedPotato66

The definition of the $e$ function is given in the first display of p. 66: $e(x) = \mathrm{e}^{2\pi \mathrm{i}x}$.

That first line basically defines $e(x)$, it's shorthand for writing
$$e(x) = e^{2 \pi i x}$$
in a way which saves having to insert the $2 \pi i$ factor every time.
$\{ - \}$ appears to just be "larger parentheses," as far as I can tell, and you can see that it's used that way later in the text. I don't know why the authors felt it was necessary on that second line.

Perhaps they used braces on the left side of that second line because there are already regular parentheses in that expression

Yes, but those parentheses are small!
